# Does addEventListener works with get element by tag name?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the color of h1 but when i am working with getElementsByTagName with addEventListener its is not performing but it works With getElementById Why?

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("site-title-heading").addEventListener("click",abc);

function abc(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("site-title-heading").style.color="yellow"

}

document.getElementById("site-title-heading").addEventListener("click",abc);

function abc(){
    document.getElementById("site-title-heading").style.color="yellow"

}
```

Comment: Notice the plural in  `getElementsByTagName`? It does not return a node, but a node list.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a HTMLCollection - Your page can have many tags with the same name on it, so naturally, this method will return all those elements. You need to add your event listener to each individual tag. If you only have  one tag that you want to add the event listener to, consider using `.querySelector()`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever things don't work, log them to the console.

> NOTE: `addEventListener` method exists on HTML Elements.

`getElementsByTagName` returns NodeList (which is array-like data structure) of HTML elements whereas `getElementById` returns an HTML Element.

So, what you can do is iterate over all the elements and assign the listener to each one of them.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("site-title-heading");

for (const el of Array.from(elements)) {
    el.addEventListener("click",abc);
}
```